# Installing Python in Windows XP

Tags: python, windows-xp, windows-installer

My work PC has restrictions that stop me from adding programs to the start menu so when I try to install Python using the Python 2.6.5 Windows installer it can't complete as it tries to add a shortcut to my start menu.

Is there a way around this? I.e another way of installing without the need for a shortcut?

**Edit:**
<del>I'll also need to install NumPy which I can't do on the Portable version of Python.</del>

Ignore me, Python portable comes with NumPy installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.portablepython.com/

Or get Ubuntu.